# What is wrong with my use of ReadProcessMemory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory, readprocessmemory

I have two processes, `A` and `B`.
A is loading a DLL with code that reads some memory locations, while B attempts to read the same memory locations on A's memory using `ReadProcessMemory`.

I get the same values until at some point I don't, which is quite puzzling. I'm missing something but I don't know what. I hope you'll help me find it.

(In both processes codes, `IMPORT_TABLE_OFFSET` is `1` and `processBaseAdress` is the starting address of `A`'s MZ header in process memory).

A's DLL code:

```
printf("processBaseAddress: %p\n", processBaseAddress);
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeaderP = processBaseAddress;
printf("ntHeaderP = %p\n", (PBYTE)dosHeaderP + dosHeaderP->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader = ((PBYTE)dosHeaderP + dosHeaderP->e_lfanew);
printf("optHeaderP = %p\n", &ntHeader->OptionalHeader);
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optionalHeader = (ntHeader->OptionalHeader);
printf("oh.aoep = %p\n", optionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
printf("oh.cs = %x\n", optionalHeader.CheckSum);
printf("DataDirectory: %p\n", optionalHeader.DataDirectory);
IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY dataDirectory = (optionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMPORT_TABLE_OFFSET]);
```

B's code:
(`hHandle` is a handle to `A`)

```
#define VERIFY_RPM(CALL_ID, RPM_CALL) {
    if(RPM_CALL==0){
        printf("Error! ReadProcessMemory(): %d. Call id: %d.\n",GetLastError(),CALL_ID);
        exit(1);
    }
}
SIZE_T bytesRead;
printf("processBaseAddress: %p\n", processBaseAddress);
VERIFY_RPM(0, ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, processBaseAddress, &dosHeader, sizeof(dosHeader), &bytesRead));
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeaderP = processBaseAddress + dosHeader.e_lfanew;
printf("ntHeaderP = %p\n", ntHeaderP);
VERIFY_RPM(1, ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ntHeaderP, &ntHeader, sizeof(ntHeader), &bytesRead));
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optionalHeader = ntHeader.OptionalHeader;
printf("oh.aoep = %p\n", optionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint);
printf("oh.cs = %x\n", optionalHeader.CheckSum);
printf("DataDirectory: %p\n", optionalHeader.DataDirectory);
VERIFY_RPM(2, ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, optionalHeader.DataDirectory + IMPORT_TABLE_OFFSET, &dataDirectory, sizeof(dataDirectory), &bytesRead));
```

A's output:

```
processBaseAddress: 1C530000
ntHeaderP = 1C5300F0
optHeaderP = 1C530108
oh.aoep = 00001327
oh.cs = d6c7
DataDirectory: 0322F8E8
```

B's output:

```
processBaseAddress: 1C530000
ntHeaderP = 1C5300F0
oh.aoep = 00001327
oh.cs = d6c7
DataDirectory: 001AEE3C
Error! ReadProcessMemory(): 299. Call id: 2.
```

It's all the same until DataDirectory.

Comment: but you make **copy** of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` - `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optionalHeader = (ntHeader->OptionalHeader);`  and `DataDirectory` point to this copy. you need use `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER* optionalHeader = &ntHeader->OptionalHeader;`

Answer (score 0):

error (by sense) is next line:

```
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER optionalHeader = (ntHeader->OptionalHeader);
```

with this you make **copy** of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER`. as result :

```
optionalHeader.DataDirectory
```

is address inside this copy but not inside original `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` inside image. you need use

```
PIMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER poptionalHeader = &ntHeader->OptionalHeader;
PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY dataDirectory = 
    &poptionalHeader->DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
```

and line

```
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, optionalHeader.DataDirectory + ..))
```

of course error because `optionalHeader.DataDirectory` - address inside local copy - have no sense in remote process. and `DataDirectory` is part of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` - after you read it - you not need separate read for `DataDirectory` - you already have this data inside `ntHeader`

also need understand that `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` - this is macros, expanded to `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32` or `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64` based on your code bit-ness. but when you read another image - it can have another bit-ness. so you always need check `Magic` member of `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` for determinate - use 32 or 64 bit structure.

correct code for read this remote can look like:

```
union {
    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader32;
    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 ntHeader64;
};

if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, ImageBase, &dosHeader, sizeof(dosHeader), 0) &&
    dosHeader.e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
{
    if (ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (PBYTE)ImageBase + dosHeader.e_lfanew, 
        &ntHeader64, sizeof(ntHeader64), 0) &&
        ntHeader.Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY dataDirectory = 0;

        switch (ntHeader.OptionalHeader.Magic)
        {
        case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR32_MAGIC:
            dataDirectory = ntHeader32.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory;
            break;
        case IMAGE_NT_OPTIONAL_HDR64_MAGIC:
            dataDirectory = ntHeader64.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory;
            break;
        }

        if (dataDirectory)
        {
            PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ImpDataDirectory = &dataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
            DbgPrint("[%x, %x]\n", ImpDataDirectory->Size, ImpDataDirectory->VirtualAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. I would expect the copy to have the same value, regardless of where it is.

Comment: @Neo - this is already only your problems if you not understand your errors